# Redirect if Browser and OS headers are blank

Tags: php, http-headers

A particular page is getting hit by someone using a block of IPs. Interestingly their headers are showing no information on their operating system or browser. How would I go about redirecting users that do not have browser or OS information in their http headers?

Is there an easy way to do this with some php?

Comment: Bad idea. Many people have browser extensions that hide the `User-Agent` header because they're concerned about privacy. You could impose IP-based rate limiting, or block that range of IP addresses.

Comment: ip is even worse, ip!= person, one person be many ip's and one ip can be hundreds of people.

Comment: @Dagon IP is not worse as long as you're careful with how you're blocking. Yes, you may be blocking a whole range of people. But this is also the only way (other than rate limiting) to safely protect yourself from this issue.

Comment: The block of IPs are from a country that the website doesn't cater to, so that may be the best solution. Any suggestions on how I would implement either of these methods to test out?

Comment: as long as you know what you are actully blocking, which is unclear here. I HATE country blocking sites, living in a country that's sometimes blocked, but getting around them is trivial. what are you really trying to stop? what's the real problem here? all sites get lots of random 'junk traffic' we mostly just ignore it

Comment: I understand that. More or less I'm just curious how this scenario could be handled, as I'm trying to teach myself php. More curiosity than anything else... not critical.

Comment: ..killed the cat. in this case if done wrong - killed your web site :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment from Colin Morelli:

> Bad idea. Many people have browser extensions that hide the `User-Agent` header because they're concerned about privacy.

However, if you want to do it, it's easy enough:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {
    // Redirect here.
    header('Location: http://example.com');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: don't do it in php if you can do it in Apache (.htaccess)

Comment: @Dagon. Indeed, that would be more efficient. Post an answer showing how it's done.

Comment: its ok, feel free to update you answer with the Apache version.